# Performance Related features for migration from .net 2003 Framework 1.1 to .net 2008 framework 3.5?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net

I am work on VB.net 2003 Framework 1.1 for last 3.5 years in windows Application.
We are currently migrating to VB.net 2008 framework 3.5, but i don't know about the features 
which related to ADO.net and which is important to performance. I know linq to SQL but our architecture is made in .net 2003 so we should follow this.
Any features which is very important to enhance the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done about 5 migrations with pure ADO.NET from 2003 to 2005.
Performance was exactly the same or better for me.
Only some big projects were a bit slower to design in visual studio (ie. typed datasets/forms)..

Improvements for ADO :

- **SQLBulkCopy**. Possibility to bulk-insert data into tables. [example](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/bulkcopy_intro1.html)
- **Faster datasets** [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163709.aspx)

Comment: I need features which are important.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get some performance improvements using generics, but that would require a bit of code change. I think generics a lot are enough reason to move from .NET 1.x to 2.0 and Linq is a good reason to move from 2.0 to 3.5 and up.